# Form Submit without Click Submit Button

Tags: javascript

Form Submit without Click Submit Button

```
<form id="formId" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/index/method') ?>" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>">

        <div id="upload-file-container">
            <input id="img" type="file" name="img" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        </div>
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Please will you elaborate your issue?

Comment: I need to submit form without click Submit Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution one:**

You can  call your form's `submit` method in the `onchange` event of your file input like this:

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ismaakeel/32tv8Lkp/2/).

**Solution Two:**

You can also define the `.submit` with an `onchange` event inline:

```
<form action="http://your-url.com">
    <input type="file" id="img" onChange="form.submit()" />
</form>
```

Here's a [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ismaakeel/e5kufrdz/1/).

**Solution Three:**

The jQuery way of doing it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#img").change(function(){
        $("#form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to submit form without click Submit Button

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById("formId").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("img").onchange = function() {
   document.getElementById("formId").submit();
};
```

Comment: a little explanation is always helpful in understanding the approach.

Comment: Shush, stalker. You may need an explanation to understand what 'onchange' and 'submit' means, but that's because you don't speak english. You won't ever get a job by writing tutorials in your blog for tasks a blindfolded 8 years old trisomic could accomplish intuitively, plus your english is terrible. No job. Remember my words.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto submit using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){ $("#formId").submit(); }, 3000); });
```

Or specify exactly when you want to submit the form.